# Default value is always returned null using object store in ESB Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Whatever value I set in the default value reference of object store, it always returns null. Where is the problem?

```
 <objectstore:retrieve config-ref="ObjectStore" key="counterValueTest"
defaultValue-ref="#['vaibhav']" targetProperty="cntvalte"
 doc:name="ObjectStore"/>
```

I actually want the default value to be set to 0.

Comment: Have you tried with `defaultValue-ref="0"`? The doc suggests it could work https://mulesoft.github.io/mule-module-objectstore/mule/objectstore-config.html#retrieve , but who knows...

Comment: Did you try to store the value first before retrieving it?. Use objcetstore:store and try to set the default value as '0' and then try to retrieve it. I have used in this way. It worked perfectly. If not working in this way, please share the full xml config to help with.

Comment: Please, specify both your _Mule Runtime_ and _ObjectStore module_ versions.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly this happens when you combine an old [*Mule ObjectStore module*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mule.modules/mule-module-objectstore) with a relatively new *Mule Runtime*.

A *Community Edition* Runtime `>= 3.6.0` should always be paired with the ObjectStore module `1.3.3`.

Using *Enterprise Edition* you are not limited to the `1.3.3` and you can use the `2+` branch of the ObjectStore module.